Vectorized way to check if a string is in a dataframe column (set of strings)?
I have a pandas dataframe df. This dataframe has a column to_filter. to_filter is either an empty set or a set of strings. This dataframe also has an integer column id. The id may not be unique.
Given an input string input, is there a vectorized way to check if each row's to_filter column contains the input string?
My goal is to get a list of ids such that input is not in the to_filter column for that given id.
e.g.,
df = {
  "id" : [55, 1, 1, 2]
  "to_filter" : [set(), set(), {"blah"}, {"blah"}] 
}
inpt = "blah"

the result should be ids = [55, 1]
I know I can do this with .apply, but that's not vectorized. df can get quite large in terms of number of rows, so I'd prefer a vectorized approach

Note that {} is not an empty set but an empty dictionary. I updated your example. I also changed input to inpt as input is a python builtin.

The other methods described here won't be performant in the same way that vectorised operations are for maths. You're dealing with Python objects sequentially no matter what's going on here.

There is no vectorial way to achieve this. You can't vectorize operations with objects/strings.
You could use map and set.isubset and reverse the boolean with ~:
inpt = 'blah'
out = df.loc[~df['to_filter'].map({inpt}.issubset), 'id']

Or the ge operator:
inpt = 'blah'
out = df.loc[~df['to_filter'].ge({inpt}), 'id']

Or a list comprehension:
out = df.loc[[not (isinstance(s, set) and inpt in s)
              for s in df['to_filter']], 'id']

Output:
0    55
1     1
Name: id, dtype: int64


Running a %timeit seems to put ge < map < list comprehension with timings 2.0 < 4.3 < 9.0 seconds respectively.

@ifly6 How many rows did you consider? Also, the list comprehension has an extra check that might be removed if we are sure there are only sets in the input. In addition, one could use a pure list comprehension with zip and without loc if a list is an acceptable output. This should be more efficient.

I was considering either 10 or 100 million rows; I don't remember anymore

A possible solution based on numpy broadcasting:
df.id.loc[df.to_numpy()[:,1] != {"blah"}]

Output:
0    55
1     1
Name: id, dtype: int64

